# Remove Rom Manager from boot

Tags: rom, rom-manager

Rom Manager is a little goofy on my phone. Each reboot I get the device builder (LG) and then before android loads I get a white box with an arrow coming out of it pointing to the little android man... then the stock android on my phone loads.... with 0 apps 0 personal data. EACH REBOOT is like a hard reset.

How do I remove Rom Manager from the boot strap? Make the phone boot like it did from the factory?